# for文を用いたデータ読み込みと連結

Tags: python

今まで以下のようなコードでデータを読み込み連結させていたのですが，最初の10行をfor文を用いるなどしてスマートにできますでしょうか．

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
da1 = pd.read_csv("data-1.csv",header=None)#
da2 = pd.read_csv("data-2.csv",header=None)#
da3 = pd.read_csv("data-3.csv",header=None)#
da4 = pd.read_csv("data-4.csv",header=None)#
da5 = pd.read_csv("data-5.csv",header=None)#
da6 = pd.read_csv("data-6.csv",header=None)#
da7 = pd.read_csv("data-7.csv",header=None)#
da8 = pd.read_csv("data-8.csv",header=None)#
da9 = pd.read_csv("data-9.csv",header=None)#
da10 = pd.read_csv("data-10.csv",header=None)#

da_all = pd.concat([da1,da2,da3,da4,da5,da6,da7,da8,da9,da10],axis=1,sort=False)
plt.plot(ch,da_all[0:12], linestyle='None',marker='o')

np.savetxt("data-all.csv", da_all, delimiter=",")#
```

試しに以下のようなコードで実行するとエラーが出てしまいました．
#前処理

#データ合体(転置前の前処理用)

```
for n1 in range(1,11):
    f"da{n1}" = pd.read_csv(f"201013-945-del-{n1}.csv",header=None)#


da_all = pd.concat([da1,da2,da3,da4,da5,da6,da7,da8,da9,da10],axis=1,sort=False)
plt.plot(ch,da_all[0:12], linestyle='None',marker='o')

np.savetxt("201013-945-del-all.csv", da_all, delimiter=",")#
```

Answer (score 1):

既にご自身で答えを出しておられる様なモノかと思いますが。。。

```py
da_all = pd.concat(
  [pd.read_csv(f"data-{i+1}.csv", header=None) for i in range(10)],
  axis=1, sort=False
)
```

Answer (score 0):

下記の様なコードがforループを使用した一般的なコードかと思います。

```py
df_list = []
for i in range(1,11):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(f"data-{i}.csv", header=None))

df_all = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1, sort=False)
```

お勧めはしませんが、質問者さんが書きたかったコードは下記かと思います。

```py
for n1 in range(1,11):
    exec("da" + str(n1) +  "= pd.read_csv(f'data-{n1}.csv',header=None)")

da_all = pd.concat([da1,da2,da3,da4,da5,da6,da7,da8,da9,da10],axis=1,sort=False)
```